# Divide dataframe into multiple Excel Files with multiple sheets (preferably using package "openxlsx")

Tags: r

i have a dataframe in R that looks like:

```
State   Type    Index1  Index2
AL      101     0,00    0,21
AL      101     0,79    0,59
AL      101     0,95    0,05
AL      201     0,55    0,77
AL      201     0,87    0,54
AL      201     0,04    0,07
AL      301     0,78    0,99
AL      301     0,34    0,66
AL      301     0,95    0,54
AK      101     0,54    0,38
AK      101     0,88    0,25
AK      101     0,04    0,82
AK      201     0,53    0,83
AK      201     0,16    0,73
AK      201     0,04    0,58
AK      301     0,58    0,14
AK      301     0,44    0,64
AK      301     0,13    0,61
AZ      101     0,31    0,09
AZ      101     0,35    0,23
AZ      101     0,36    0,20
AZ      201     0,87    0,31
AZ      201     0,41    0,64
AZ      201     0,30    0,04
AZ      301     0,94    0,05
AZ      301     0,65    0,16
AZ      301     0,57    0,79
AR      101     0,42    0,67
AR      101     0,81    0,79
AR      101     0,23    0,37
AR      201     0,17    0,32
AR      201     0,41    0,47
AR      201     0,60    0,79
AR      301     0,57    0,07
AR      301     0,76    0,17
AR      301     0,89    0,23
```

I need to divide it with package "openxlsx" into multiple Excel files. Each file should have name "[State].xlsx" and contain three sheets with names that are unique values of Type - 101, 201 and 301. Each sheet ("101", "201", "301") should contain all four columns from initial dataframe but only with those cells where Type is the same as the name of sheet.
Package "openxlsx" is here necessary because layout of each Excel file should be also formatted, and "openxlsx" as i understood provides the best opportunities for that among other packages in r.

I have already divided dataframe (that was initially exported to .csv) into several Excel files by name of state.

```
state_type_relation <- read.csv("dataframe.csv", header = T, sep =";", dec =",", encoding = "UTF-8")
state_type_relation_split <- split(state_type_relation, state_type_relation$State)
names <- names(state_type_relation_split)
paths = paste0("T:/", names, ".xlsx")
for (i in seq_along(state_type_relation_split))
{
  write.xlsx(state_type_relation_split[[i]], paths[i])
}
```

However i still cannot understand how to create sheets within each file with names of Type. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `for` loop you could `split` the data to be exported by `Type` before exporting to XL:

```r
library(openxlsx)

# Create a temp directory
path <- tempdir()

state_type_relation_split <- split(state_type_relation, state_type_relation$State)
fn <- names(state_type_relation_split)
paths = file.path(path, paste0(fn, ".xlsx"))

for (i in seq_along(state_type_relation_split)) {
  dat <- split(state_type_relation_split[[i]], state_type_relation_split[[i]]$Type)
  write.xlsx(dat, paths[[i]])
}

# Check that three Sheets have been created
lapply(paths, readxl::excel_sheets)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "101" "201" "301"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "101" "201" "301"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "101" "201" "301"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "101" "201" "301"
```